# Using Liquibase contexts to conditionally activate/deactivate a change set

Tags: liquibase

We have changeset one:

```
--changeset change_one runOnChange:true
```

And changeset two:

```
--changeset change_two runOnChange:true context:kansas
```

change_one applies to all our installations but change_two only applies to our "kansas" installation.   We want to ensure that change_two is executed whenever change_one is changed - how can we do this?

change_one has runOnChange:true so it will run whenever changed.  But how can we ensure change_two runs when change_one executes - but only when we pass context:kansas?

Comment: Can't you just use a `<preCondition>` with a `<changeSetExecuted>` on changeset two? So it gets only executed after changeSet one was executed?

Comment: @Jens I ended up using a precondition.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

When you run Liquibase without specifying any contexts, you might expect that no contexts should be activated, but in fact it [works as documented](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/contexts.html) in that ALL contexts will be activated. If you use contexts in your change logs to disable change sets, you will have to set a contexts parameter whenever you execute Liquibase. e.g.

```
mvn process-resources liquibase:update -Dliquibase.contexts=production
```

You should also check into the [labels](http://blog.liquibase.org/2014/11/contexts-vs-labels.html) feature added in Liquibase 3.3. The difference is that the caller can specify some sophisticated expressions. e.g.

```
mvn process-resources liquibase:update -Dliquibase.labels=!kansas
```

Note, however, that the behavior is the same as contexts when no label expression is specified.

Example Change Sets:

```
<changeSet id="tag-v1" author="a">
    <tagDatabase tag="v1"/>
</changeSet>

<changeSet id="tag-v1a" author="a" context="kansas">
    <tagDatabase tag="v1a"/>
</changeSet>

<changeSet id="tag-v1b" author="a" labels="kansas">
    <tagDatabase tag="v1b"/>
</changeSet>
```